# What is the eta expansion in Scala?

Tags: scala, eta-expansion

I am new to Scala. I just heard the term "eta expansion" and roughly know that it means to expand a method to a function object. But I find few resources in SO that systematically introduce it.

I am curious about how eta expansion works in Scala. What are the scenarios that eta expansion are needed? And how *eta expansion* is implemented in Scala?

I roughly know that in cases like this:

```
def someMethod(x: Int): Int = x * x
```

`someMethod _` will roughly be translated to a new function object like this:

```
new Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = x * x
}
```

Is it all that Scala does?

Comment: A pretty good (if dated) explanation of eta-expansion in Scala - https://gleichmann.wordpress.com/2011/01/09/functional-scala-turning-methods-into-functions/

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The definition, and some examples, are given in http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values.

> `someMethod _` will roughly be translated to a new function object like this:

Not quite: it's actually

```
new Function1[Int, Int] {
  def apply(x: Int): Int = someMethod(x)
}
```

The difference matters e.g. if `someMethod` is overridden somewhere.

> Is it all that Scala does?

You also need to take into account what happens if the method takes multiple parameter lists (you get a function which returns a function) or by-name parameters.

> What are the scenarios that eta expansion are needed?

1. When you specifically ask for it (e.g. `someMethod _`).
2. When you use a method (with parameters) where a value of a function type (or a SAM type in Scala 2.12) is expected. E.g.

   ```
   def foo(f: Int => Int) = ???

   foo(someMethod)
   ```
3. That's it.

Note that using eta-expansion and an anonymous function with placeholders (`someMethod(_)`) can behave differently due to type inference, implicits, etc.

Answer (score 24):

[Eta expansion](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion) In high level, is a process of translating methods into functions. Why? What? Aren't them the same? Let's explain:

A **method** in scala is what we know as `def someMethodName(SomePramList): SomeReturnType`. It starts with `def`. It may have parameter list, or even maybe more then 1. For example:

```
def numAdder(num1: Int)(num2: Int): Int = 
    num1 + num2
```

A **function**, or `lambda` function looks something like: `(SomeParams) => SomeReturnType`. For example:

```
val aFunction: Int => Int => Int = (num1: Int) => (num2: Int) => num1 + num2
```

**Important to understand about functions is that this syntax is basically a syntactic sugar to `FunctionN.apply` method.**

> **What are the scenarios that eta expansion are needed?**

Some examples:

**Example1 - Applying a method inside `map` (or `filter`, `flatMap` etc)**

Writing such code:

```
def addPlus1(x: Int): Int = x + 1
List(1,2,3).map(addPlus1)
```

The compiler needs to have a **function** inside the `map`. So, it transforms the method given into a function:
`List(1,2,3).map(x => addPlus1(x))`. This is `Eta expansion`.

**Example2 - currying**

When defining curried method, for example:

```
def numAdder(num1: Int)(num2: Int): Int = 
    num1 + num2
```

And them creating a **function** like:

```
val curriedFunction: Int => Int = numAdder(4)
//or
val curriedFunction2 = numAdder(4) _
```

We defined a **function** out of a method. This is `Eta expansion`.

**Some more examples**

Defined a method which accepts a function value:

```
def someMethod(f: () => Int): Int = f()
def method(): Int = 10
```

And then run:

```
someMethod(method)
```

will transform the method `method` into a function. This is `Eta expansion`