# <Functional Programing in Scala> simulateMachine

Tags: scala

Exercise 13

The official answer is:

```
  def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- sequence(inputs map (modify[Machine] _ compose update))
    s <- get
  } yield (s.coins, s.candies)
```

the position of the second placeholder in the second line really confuses me, the right answer from my perspective should be this:

```
  def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- sequence(inputs map ((modify[Machine] compose update) _))
    s <- get
  } yield (s.coins, s.candies)
```

please help me understand why the first answer is right, thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

`modify`, I believe, is some known method, so placeholder is just an [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala) in of the method, converting it to the [`Function1`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function1.html) and enabling using of its methods like [`compose`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map[B](f:A=>B):List[B])

So without placeholder after `modify[Machine]` in `modify[Machine] compose update` there may be compile error sometimes. But if there is not, then no need for placeholder after full expression either, because it's guaranteed that result of `compose` is a `Function1` and could be use as parameter for [`map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#map[B](f:A=>B):List[B])

Answer (score 1):

The question here is how actually **compose** works: 
"compose makes a new function that composes other functions f(g(x))",
f compose g can be translated to: "execute f after g"

```
scala> val fComposeG = f _ compose g _
fComposeG: (String) => java.lang.String = <function>
```

This *composition* returns another function which accepts an Input and return a new State[A, S].

The compiler lets you to make something like that:

```
val ll = inputs map update
```

Now ll is a **List[Machine => Machine**] which is exactly what *update function* needs. After modify it´s necessary the underscore, otherwise the compiler alerts *"missing argument list for method modify...."*

Answer (score 0):

`modify` is a method, we must convert it to a function to be able to use `compose`. The way we do this in scala is by using placeholder syntax or by using [eta expansion](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values).

(`modify[Machine] _`) is equivalent to (`f => modify[Machine](f)`)

So another way to write this is:

```
def modifyFunction: ((Machine => Machine)) => State[Machine, Unit] = f => modify[Machine](f)

def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- sequence(inputs map (modifyFunction compose update))
    s <- get
} yield (s.coins, s.candies)
```