# In Scala, what is the difference between fun _ and fun as parameters

Tags: scala

Lets say we have a function `def fun(x: X): X => Y` and we pass this function as a parameter to another function using `fun _` instead of just `fun`. I understand that `fun _` is actually a function value, while `fun` refers to a function definition.

For example let:

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4)

def fun(x: Int) = {println(x); x + 1}
```

Then Running:

```
//This line works
a.map(fun _)

//This one also works, even though "fun" is not a function value
a.map(fun)
```

They have the same output:

```
1
2
3
4
resX: List[Int] = List(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

For the most part they seem to work the same, are there any examples in which the function value is not equivalent to the function definition?

Comment: `fun` is a method, not a function. The distinction is important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the eta expansion in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala)

Comment: Post an actual example showing "we pass this function as a parameter to another function using `fun _` instead of just `fun`" and "For the most part they seem to work the same". It'll be easier for us. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: "Function value" is a very misleading term. (1) `fun` is a method, it has no value and can't be passed as a parameter, (2) `fun _` or using `fun` in a functional context (including functional parameter) will perform η-expansion (another misleading term borrowed from λ-calculus, link above provided by @Haspemulator).

Answer (score 4):

In the [signature of `map`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#map[B](f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.Map[B]), you can see that it's expecting a

> "function" to apply to each element

But in your code, `fun` is a regular *method* in a class. So when you do:

```
a.map(fun _)
```

you are *explicitly* asking for eta-expansion. When you do:

```
a.map(fun)
```

you are *implicitly* asking for eta-expansion.

Because `fun` is a "method", and is being used in a place where a `Function` type is expected, it's [automagically converted](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion) to that type. Basically to something like:

```
new Function1[Int, Int] {
    def apply(x: Int): Int = fun(x)
}
```

This transformation converting the name `fun` to a `Function` is called `eta-expansion`. See [documentation](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#method-values) for details.

Unfortunately, there are various ways of doing what you're doing - `a.map(fun)`, `a.map(fun _)`, `a.map(fun(_))` and `a.map(x => fun(x))`. This is one of those frequent scenarios in Scala where you can explicitly do something yourself, or explicitly ask the compiler to do it for you, or just let the compiler do it implicitly. They can have different behaviors because of implicits and it can be a major source of confusion. Also, `_` is heavily overloaded in the language, only adding to the confusion. So I use implicit behavior sparingly in general.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out in the comments, you need to use the `fun _` syntax (which performs an [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala)) when you need a value (methods have no value by themselves). Within the context of a map (or other functional contexts) an eta expansion is performed on the method implicitly. There are some cases where the eta expansion must be triggered manually.

As a concrete example of where an  explicit eta expansion is needed, consider this valid snippet:

```
def f1(x: Int): Int = 2*x

def f2(x: Int): Int = 3*x

val fList1 = List(f1 _, f2 _)

fList1.map(_(2)) // List(4, 6)
```

as opposed to this invalid snippet.

```
val fList2 = List(f1, f2)
```

Comment: `val fList2: List[Int => Int] = List(f1, f2)` works too.

Comment: Is there an implicit conversion for that?

Comment: Compiler performs η-expansion whenever it sees a method where function is expected, in this case `List` elements are expected to be of type `Int => Int`.

Comment: Hmm, so functions aren't expected when I do `val fList = List(f1, f2) `?