# How is the underscore different from a placeholder in a partially applied function in Scala?

Tags: scala

I've been trying my best to understand the underscore syntax and I've found various threads involving this but I'm still unclear on one use:

I see this in Odersky's book (pg 150 and 151 in Version 3)

```
someNumbers.foreach(println _)
```

Apparently this replaces an entire parameter list? I don't see how this is different from a normal placeholder. It goes on to say that this is not a placeholder for a single parameter... it is a placeholder for an entire list. This is unclear to me. How is this different from a placeholder?

Is this the same concept:

```
def add(x: Int, y: Int) = x + y
val addFunction = add _
// Does this just copy the parameter list?
addFunction(1,2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `add _` or `println _` the underscore is not a placeholder. You can see it if you replace `add _` with `add(_)` in your second example. In this case, the code will not compile. If it was a placeholder, you could switch the syntaxes.

It is called **eta-expansion** and is used to convert a method into a function. In Scala thoses two notions are a little bit different :

- A *function* can be defined with the syntax: `val fn: A => B = (a: A) => ...`
- A *method* is defined with the syntax: `def fn(a: A): B = ...`

Generally, the two syntaxes can be used indifferently. But sometimes it is required to explicitly transform a method into a function with this syntax.

You can find more informations here : [What is the eta expansion in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala)