# Rewrite scala code to be more functional

Tags: scala

I am trying to teach myself Scala whilst at the same time trying to write code that is idiomatic of a functional language, i.e. write better, more elegant, functional code.

I have the following code that works OK:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import java.time.LocalDate
object DataFrameExtensions_ {
  implicit class DataFrameExtensions(df: DataFrame){
    def featuresGroup1(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
    def featuresGroup2(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
  }
}
import DataFrameExtensions_._
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
val groupBy = Seq("a","b")
val asAt = LocalDate.now()
val dataFrames = Seq(df.featuresGroup1(groupBy, asAt),df.featuresGroup2(groupBy, asAt))
```

The last line bothers me though. The two functions (`featuresGroup1`, `featuresGroup2`) both have the same signature:

```scala
scala> :type df.featuresGroup1(_,_)
(Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> :type df.featuresGroup2(_,_)
(Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
```

and take the same `val`s as parameters so I assume I can write that line in a more functional way (perhaps using `.map` somehow) that means I can write the parameter list just once and pass it to both functions. I can't figure out the syntax though. I thought maybe I could construct a list of those functions but that doesn't work:

```scala
scala> Seq(featuresGroup1, featuresGroup2)
<console>:23: error: not found: value featuresGroup1
       Seq(featuresGroup1, featuresGroup2)
           ^
<console>:23: error: not found: value featuresGroup2
       Seq(featuresGroup1, featuresGroup2)
                           ^
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought maybe I could construct a list of those functions but that doesn't work:

Why are you writing just `featuresGroup1/2` here when you already had the correct syntax `df.featuresGroup1(_,_)` just above?

```
Seq(df.featuresGroup1(_,_), df.featuresGroup2(_,_)).map(_(groupBy, asAt))
```

`df.featuresGroup1 _` should work as well.

`df.featuresGroup1` by itself would work if you had an expected type, e.g.

```
val dataframes: Seq[(Seq[String], LocalDate) => DataFrame] = 
  Seq(df.featuresGroup1, df.featuresGroup2)
```

but in this specific case providing the expected type is more verbose than using lambdas.

Comment: *Why are you writing just featuresGroup1/2 here when you already had the correct syntax df.featuresGroup1(_,_) just above?* Probably because I'm still learning

Comment: Your suggestion seems to work and is closest to the pure functional approach I was envisaging. Let me just check it all through and then I shall accept your answer. thank you :)

Comment: P.S. There's a small typo in your answer. `asAt`, not `asAdt`

Comment: *in this specific case providing the expected type is more verbose than using lambdas* Agreed. I prefer the type inferencing provided by the lambda approach

Comment: `Seq(df.featuresGroup1(_,_), df.featuresGroup2(_,_)).map(_(groupBy, asAt))` does work. `Seq(df.featuresGroup1 _, df.featuresGroup2 _).map(_(groupBy, asAt))` does not, it fails with error **<console>:26: error: missing argument list for method featuresGroup1 in class DataFrameExtensions | 
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected. | 
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `featuresGroup1 _` or `featuresGroup1(_,_)` instead of `featuresGroup1`.**

Comment: That's weird, it even suggests ` _`. Since you are using Spark, it's probably an older Scala version, but I don't remember any recent changes linked to this.

Comment: I'm glad you think its weird, I concur :) . Scala version is 2.11.12

Comment: Still got that typo :)

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

> I thought maybe I could construct a list of those functions but that doesn't work

You need to explicitly perform [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala) to turn methods into functions (they are not the same in Scala), by using an underscore operator:

```
val funcs = Seq(featuresGroup1 _, featuresGroup2 _)
```

or by using placeholders:

```
val funcs = Seq(featuresGroup1(_, _), featuresGroup2(_, _))
```

And you are absolutely right about using `map` operator:

```
val dataFrames = funcs.map(f => f(groupBy, asAdt))
```

---

I strongly recommend against using implicits of types `String` or `Seq`, as if used in multiple places, these lead to subtle bugs that are not immediately obvious from the code and the code will be prone to breaking when it's moved somewhere.

If you want to use implicits, wrap them into a custom types:

```
case class DfGrouping(groupBy: Seq[String]) extends AnyVal

implicit val grouping: DfGrouping = DfGrouping(Seq("a", "b"))
```

Comment: Thx Oleg. I tried `val funcs = Seq(featuresGroup1 _, featuresGroup2 _)` but that failed: `<console>:24: error: not found: value featuresGroup1`. Could this be because those functions are defined in an implicit class?

Comment: `Seq(df.featuresGroup1(_,_), df.featuresGroup2(_,_)).map(_(groupBy, asAt))` does the trick

Comment: I appreciate your recommendation not to use implicits. I admit when I saw @vindev's suggestion it left me slightly uneasy as I wondered "what if I've got multiple implicit values" and did think that subtle bugs could creep in. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 1):

Why no just create a function in `DataFrameExtensions` to do so?

```
def getDataframeGroups(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: String) = Seq(featuresGroup1(groupBy,asAt), featuresGroup2(groupBy,asAt))
```

Comment: thx @RoberMP. Thx, yes that works. I'm not going to accept your answer yet though (I promise I will later) as I'm interested to read any other suggestions that might be posited, I'm particularly interested to know if this can be done with a `.map()` rather than using a *helper* function (which is how I think of your solution).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create a list of functions as below:

```
val funcs:List[DataFrame=>(Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]  = List(_.featuresGroup1, _.featuresGroup1)
funcs.map(x => x(df)(groupBy, asAt))
```

It seems you have a list of functions which convert a `DataFrame` to another `DataFrame`. If that is the pattern, you could go a little bit further with `Endo` in `Scalaz`

Comment: thx Binzi. I tried: `val funcs:List[DataFrame=>(Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]  = List(_.featuresGroup1, _.featuresGroup1)` which failed with `<console>:24: error: type mismatch;|found   : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame|(which expands to)  org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]|required: (Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame|(which expands to)  (Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]`

Comment: It works well from my here
funcs: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame => ((Seq[String], java.time.LocalDate) => org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame)] = List(<function1>, <function1>)
res1: List[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = List([number: int, word: string], [number: int, word: string])

Comment: tried that, got `<console>:1: error: ';' expected but '=' found.` :( . Sorry, I'm sure I'm just being a dumb newbie but I just can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Sorry my reply was not code, it was the return result of the lines of code in the answer. I used your sample code in the questions. it works well with my answer. maybe there is something in your  REPL

Comment: ah, OK. Showing my naivety :) I'll keep investigating. thx. At the time of writing Oleg's suggestion seems closest to the pure functional solution I envisaged, but it doesn't work for my scenario and I can't figure out why :(

Comment: If you copy an screen shot of the code and error, I may help to find it out. This is actually one of the most important pure functional concepts, `curried` and `uncurried`. The data type in the list is a curried function. Scala supports curried function. I would suggest you do more investigations about the error. Curried function is a very important concept in FP.  In FP, everything can be made as a function.

Comment: I'm going to post a repro as a github gist. Watch this space.

Comment: I got your code to work. not sure what I was doing wrong yesterday. Posted here: https://gist.github.com/jamiekt/cea2dab3ea8de91489b31045b302e011 as a gist. Your code is on these two lines: https://gist.github.com/jamiekt/cea2dab3ea8de91489b31045b302e011#file-script-scala-L28-L29

Answer (score 0):

I like this answer best, courtesy of Alexey Romanov.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SparkSession}
import java.time.LocalDate
object DataFrameExtensions_ {
  implicit class DataFrameExtensions(df: DataFrame){
    def featuresGroup1(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
    def featuresGroup2(groupBy: Seq[String], asAt: LocalDate): DataFrame = {df}
  }
}
import DataFrameExtensions_._
val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]")).enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._
val df = Seq((8, "bat"),(64, "mouse"),(-27, "horse")).toDF("number", "word")
val groupBy = Seq("a","b")
val asAt = LocalDate.now()
Seq(df.featuresGroup1(_,_), df.featuresGroup2(_,_)).map(_(groupBy, asAt))
```