# scala "print(_)" outputs nothing, why?

Tags: string, scala, printing, format

I've this codesnippet:

```
val O = Array(3, "str")
for (o <- O) print(o)
println("\n===")
for (_ <- O) print(_)
println("\n===")
```

It prints

```
3str
===

===
```

Why the second for+print(_) doesn't print anything? Any explanations?

Comment: use for (_ <- O) print(\`_\`) you will get the expected result

Comment: Alternatively, use `O.foreach(print)` (or `O.foreach(print(_))` or `O.foreach(x => print(x))`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for (_ <- O)` **translation**: Pull each element from `O` but don't assign them to anything. Just throw those values away.

`print(_)` **translation**: For each unused element from `O`, use [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala) to turn the `print()` method into a proper function that does the same thing. Then throw it away.

Added reference: [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)