# Error in using composed function in further function composition

Tags: scala, function-composition

I am having trouble understanding why I am unable to use a composed function and compose a new one. For eg: I have two functions `f` and `g` and I create a composed function `composed1` from these. I tried to combine composed with fourth function `lastOne` and it fails.

I want to make two composed functions and for the second one Is there a way I can reuse the first composed function?

```
scala> def f(x: Int)(y: Int) = {
     | x + y
     | }
f: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> def g(a: Int)(b: Int) = {
     | a + b
     | }
g: (a: Int)(b: Int)Int

scala> def composed1(a: Int, b: Int) = {
     | f(a) _ andThen g(b)
     | }
composed1: (a: Int, b: Int)Int => Int

scala> composed1(2, 2)(5)
res1: Int = 9

scala> def lastOne(l: Int)(x: Int) = {
     | l + x
     | }
lastOne: (l: Int)(x: Int)Int

scala> def composed2(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = {
     | composed1(a, b) _ andThen lastOne(c)
     | }
<console>:14: error: _ must follow method; cannot follow Int => Int
       composed1(a, b) _ andThen lastOne(c)
                ^
<console>:14: error: missing argument list for method lastOne
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `lastOne _` or `lastOne(_)(_)` instead of `lastOne`.
       composed1(a, b) _ andThen lastOne(c)
```

When I use all of them together it works

```
scala> def test(x: Int, y: Int, z: Int) = {
     | f(x) _ andThen g(y) _ andThen lastOne(z)
     | }
test: (x: Int, y: Int, z: Int)Int => Int

scala> test(2, 2, 4)(5)
res9: Int = 13
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f()()` and `g()()`, as you define them, are methods. [Methods are not functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529184/4993128) but methods can be promoted to functions via "[eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39445018/4993128)". One way to do that is using the underscore in place of a passed parameter.

`andThen()` is a method on the [`Function` trait](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/current/scala/Function1.html) that takes a function as an argument and returns a new function. It looks as if you can also use a method as the passed argument but it is silently being promoted to `Function` status.

So `composed1()` looks like a method but it is actually a `Function`, because that's what `andThen()` returns, and you can't apply the underscore eta expansion to a `Function`. It only works on methods.

As an experiment, turn `f()()` into a `Function` that does the same thing...

```
def f :Int => Int => Int = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x + y
```

...now `composed1()` won't compile.

So, now that we know that `composed1()` is a `Function`, how do we get what we want from `composed2()`? Simple. Skip the underscore.

```
def composed2(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) =
  composed1(a, b) andThen lastOne(c)

composed2(2, 2, 4)(5)   //res0: Int = 13
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I have accepted the answer. Quick question, In many places I see def is used to create a method and `val` is used to create a function, in your example you have used `def` to create a function. Is it this symbol `=>` that makes your definition a function instead of method?

Comment: @Aandal; Defining a function using `val` is more usual, and makes more sense, than using `def`. I put it together rather quickly. In answer to your question, yes, the `=>` is a big clue that we're dealing with a function. Put the `f` method in the REPL and it will respond with `f: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int`. If you then ask the REPL `:type f` you'll get an error. The function `f`, on the other hand, is clearly type `f: Int => (Int => Int)` and the REPL will gladly tell you so.