# Scala: no-name parameters in function with List and Option

Tags: scala, function, scala-cats

2 different examples, the first one works:

```
  import cats.syntax.either._
  val e = 10.asRight[String]
  def i2s(i:Int):String = i.toString
  e.map(i => List(i2s(i))) //using explicit parameter
  e.map(List(i2s(_)))   //using no-name _ parameter
```

Now the same example with Option is not compiled:

```
e.map(Option(i2s(_)))
```

The error:

```
Error:(27, 15) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[Int => String]
 required: Int => ?
  e.map(Option(i2s(_)))
```

With explicit parameter it works fine:

```
e.map(i => Option(i2s(i)))
```

In both cases apply method is invoked with List and Option. `List.apply` signature:

```
 def apply[A](xs: A*): List[A] = ???
```

`Option.apply` signature:

```
 def apply[A](x: A): Option[A]
```

Please explain the difference.

Answer (score 4):

Both of your `List` examples compile but they don't mean the same thing and don't produce the same results.

```
e.map(i => List(i2s(i))) //res0: scala.util.Either[String,List[String]] = Right(List(10))
e.map(List(i2s(_)))      //java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
```

The 1st is easy to understand, so what's going on with the 2nd?

What's happening is that you're using [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C153.5270) to create an `Int => String` function from the `i2s()` method. You then populate a `List` with that single function as the only element in the list, and then try to retrieve the value at index `10`, which doesn't exist, thus the exception.

If you change the 1st line to `val e = 0.asRight[String]` then the exception goes away because something *does* exist at index `0`, the function that was just put in there.

This compiles because a `List` instance will accept an `Int` as a parameter (via the hidden `apply()` method), but an `Option` *instance* does not have an `apply()` method that takes an `Int` (*) so that can't be compiled.

(*) The `Option` object *does* have an `apply()` method, but that's a different animal.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple things at play here as to why your first example with `List[A]` works. First, let's look at the expansion that happens on the expression:

```
val res: Either[String, Int => String] = 
  e.map[Int => String](List.apply[Int => String](((x$1: Int) => FlinkTest.this.i2s(x$1))));
```

Notice two things:

- The expansion of the lambda expression happens **inside** `List.apply`, and perhaps not as you expected, for it to be outside of `List.apply`, like this:

  ```
  e.map(i => List(i2s(i))
  ```
- The return type from `.map` is somehow not `Either[String, List[Int => String]]`, but `Either[String, Int => String]`. This is due to the fact that in it's hierarchy chain, `List[A]` extends `PartialFunction[Int, A]`, thus allowing it to transform the result into a function type.

This doesn't work for `Option[A]`, as it doesn't extend `PartialFunction` anywhere in it's type hierarchy.

The key takeaway here is that the expansion of the lambda expression doesn't work as you expect, as `List(i2s(_))` expands to `List(i2s(x => i2s(x))` and not `List(i => i2s(i))`. For more on underscore expansion, see [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)