# Try to pass a function to a value but the function run

Tags: scala, f#

I have this code:

Scala:

```
object C extends App{
 def a(): Unit ={
   println("a")
  }

  val b=a
}
```

f#:

```
let a=printfn "%A" "a"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
  let b=a
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

I only want to pass the function as a value `a`, not to run it. Why, when I run the program, I get "a" written to the console?

Comment: In F# code you need to make `a` a function to work as you expect. Currently it's a value that is calculated when you assign it to `b`. So just add (): `let a() =printfn "%A" "a"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`b` is evaluated when that line is of your code is reached.

try using `lazy` instead. this will calculate the value of `b` only when you call it.

```
object C extends App{
 def a(): Unit ={
  println("a")
 }

 lazy val b = a // Nothing will happen here
 b // Now "a" will be printed
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Scala code `a()` is a method. As such it cannot be passed as an argument or assigned as a value, but it can be tuned into a function, via [eta-expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39445018/4993128), which *can* be passed as an argument and/or assigned as a value.

```
val b = a _
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want `a` to be a function you need to give it parameters:

```
let a () = printfn "%A" "a"
```

then call it in `main`:

```
let main argv = 
  let b = a ()
  0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: I think the question is about Scala not F#

Answer (score 2):

Adding on to jwvh 's answer, the spirit of your F# code may be more accurately represented by defining `a` as a function instead of a method:

```
val a = () => println("a")

val b = a
```

This will work as intended, no eta expansion required.