# Spark Scala Register UDF - Why I need to pass underscore (_) at the end of function

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have created an UDF in Scala and when I was trying to register this UDF with just function name it was showing me error.

**Not Working**

```
def IPConvertUDF = spark.udf.register("IPConvertUDF", IPConvert)
```

**Error**

```
error: missing argument list for method IPConvert
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `IPConvert _` or `IPConvert(_)` instead of `IPConvert`.
def IPConvertUDF = spark.udf.register("IPConvertUDF", IPConvert)
```

> And so I added extra `_` after method name and it worked.

**Works perfectly**

```
def IPConvertUDF = spark.udf.register("IPConvertUDF", IPConvert _)
```

Would someone be able to explain be what is the meaning of extra `_` after the method name?

Comment: what is an UDF?

Comment: I think it's a way of referencing a method as an expression. That is similar to java's method reference `ClassOrInstanceName::IPConvert`

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well the short answer is, you are trying to pass a `method` where a `function` is expected as an argument. [Methods are not functions](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/06/09/methods-functions.html).
Let's dig a bit deeper.

Lets try with simple add `function` first

```
 val add:(Int,Int) => Int = (val1,val2) => val1+val2

 spark.udf.register("add",add)
```

The above code compiled without any error.  The reason is `add` is a `function`.

Now lets try the same `add` as a `method`

```
def add(val1:Int,val2:Int): Int ={
     val1+val2
   }

 spark.udf.register("add",add)
```

Now you get an error saying `error: missing argument list for method add`.
As I mentioned, `register(..)` is expecting function and methods cannot be passed as arguments.

`_` is a shorthand for partially applied function.In other words , add method is converted into `partially applied function` and that's the reason the error has disappeared.

```
spark.udf.register("add",add _)
```