# Calling an anonymous function inside a map method

Tags: scala, eta-expansion

I was making a constructor with multiple possible arguments, when I realized my IDE was pointing out a type discrepancy:

```
  case class PathAndColumns(path: String, column: Array[Column]) {

  def this(path: String, column: Column) {
    this(path, Array(column))
  }

  def this(path: String, column: String) {
    this(path, column.split(",").map( _ => col(_))) // : Array[String=>Column]
  }
```

So I tried just passing the *col* function.

```
  def this(path: String, column: String) {
    this(path, column.split(",").map(col)) // I work!
  }
```

It works, and then, trying to understand why, I ended up with:

```
  def this(path: String, column: String) {
    this(path, column.split(",").map(letsSee)) // I work as well
  }

  def letsSee(myStringCol: String): Column = {
    (() => col(myStringCol))() // A pair of extra parenthesis to simulate a call
  }
```

So I found out that passing an anonymous function to methods like **map** doesn't return the result, but rather the whole function (because it's treated as an object I suppose).

So how do I make **this** work in order to get a Column rather than the function type, without declaring it separatedly?

```
  def this(path: String, column: String) {
    this(path, column.split(",").map(_ => {
      col(_)
    }))
  }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is that you replace

```
_ => col(_)
```

with

```
x => col(x)
```

The problem is that you are treating `_` is a normal variable identifier, but it isn't. The two uses of `_` in the first expression are completely independent.

The first `_` is a placeholder for the argument to an anonymous function. The syntax `_ => ...` means that you are defining a function but will not use the argument to that function when calculating the result.

The second `_` is a placeholder for the argument to `col`. The syntax `col(_)` turns the method `col` into a free function.

Comment: Ah so my problem came from not understanding correctly what _ was doing here... I will leave my question and the duplicate link just in case someone falls into the same problem, so they can be pointed out in the right direction. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The two underscores in

```
.map(_ => col(_))
```

desugar to

```
.map(x1 => x2 => col(x2))
```

instead of the desired

```
.map(x1 => col(x1))
```

On the other hand, the following works

```
.map(col)
```

due to [eta-expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39446986/5205022).

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is passing to map an anonymous function returning another function with type String => Column. You have to remove placeholder _ from the left part of your function literal, or use explicit argument name.