# Understanding Scala for comprehension in this example code

Tags: scala

I'm new to the Scala world and have some questions regarding following code.

```
sealed trait Input
case object Coin extends Input
case object Turn extends Input

case class Machine(locked: Boolean, candies: Int, coins: Int)

object Candy {
  def update = (i: Input) => (s: Machine) =>
    (i, s) match {
      case (_, Machine(_, 0, _)) => s
      case (Coin, Machine(false, _, _)) => s
      case (Turn, Machine(true, _, _)) => s
      case (Coin, Machine(true, candy, coin)) =>
        Machine(false, candy, coin + 1)
      case (Turn, Machine(false, candy, coin)) =>
        Machine(true, candy - 1, coin)
    }

  def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- sequence(inputs map (modify[Machine] _ compose update))
    s <- get
  } yield (s.coins, s.candies)
}

case class State[S, +A](run: S => (A, S)) {
  def map[B](f: A => B): State[S, B] =
    flatMap(a => unit(f(a)))
  def map2[B,C](sb: State[S, B])(f: (A, B) => C): State[S, C] =
    flatMap(a => sb.map(b => f(a, b)))
  def flatMap[B](f: A => State[S, B]): State[S, B] = State(s => {
    val (a, s1) = run(s)
    f(a).run(s1)
  })
}
object State {
    def modify[S](f: S => S): State[S, Unit] = for {
        s <- get // Gets the current state and assigns it to `s`.
        _ <- set(f(s)) // Sets the new state to `f` applied to `s`.
    } yield ()

    def get[S]: State[S, S] = State(s => (s, s))

    def set[S](s: S): State[S, Unit] = State(_ => ((), s))

    def sequence[S,A](sas: List[State[S, A]]): State[S, List[A]] =
        sas.foldRight(unit[S, List[A]](List()))((f, acc) => f.map2(acc)(_ :: _))

    def unit[S, A](a: A): State[S, A] =
        State(s => (a, s))
}
```

1. In `simulateMachine` method, what is the first and second `_`? Feels first one is an ignored output, are those two stands for the same value?
2. The `get` is from State, how does it get the state of Machine?
3. `yield` output a Tuple, how does it matching return type `State[Machine, (Int, Int)]`
4. How to call this `simulateMachine` method? Looks like I need do initiate Machine state somewhere.

I don't think [this document](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/for-comprehensions.html) can give me the right comprehension about what is happening under the hood. How can I understand it better?

Comment: This code snippet you've posted does not compile :) The thing is, the missing parts that would make it compile are critical for understanding this snippet. Could you please check if you have omitted some parts of the actual code? Hint: I believe `State` class/companion object should at least have `map` and `flatMap`

Comment: You are completely right, I added them now.

Comment: You have a lot of questions, all of them are already answered. **for comprehensions** are just [syntatic sugar for calls to `map` / `flatMap` & `withFilert`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/yield.html). For understand how **State** works, I would recommend you to search for tutorials about it and write your own implementation. Finally, the first `_` is used to ignore the output and the second one is used to create a **function** from the `modify[Machine]` **method**, it is called eta-expansion.

Comment: Thanks Luis, that link definitely helps, can you help me on the #4 question as well?

Comment: @Mengo As I said, it would be good if you search for tutorials about the **State Monad**. But yes, at the end, a `State[S, A]` is basically a `Function[S => (A, S)]`, so given an initial state `A` it will return a value `A` and a new state. `get` basically returns a State that returns the passed state as the value. Finally, for using the composed State returned by the `simulateMachine` method, you need to call `run(initialState)`, I do not know what that initial state should be, maybe a `Machine(locked = false, candies = 10, coins = 0)`?

Comment: It looks like you arrived in scala world through the wardrobe, as opposed to the looking glass.

Comment: @som-snytt This is from the book *Functional Programming in Scala*, I like the book, and anthor said he'll use Scala as a vehicle to learn FP, looks like this vehicle is too fancy for me.

Comment: @Mengo I believe that book assumes you already know Scala. What is your ultimate goal, to learn Scala? To learn FP? Or to learn FP in Scala?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The book assumes no Scala experience and it has explain syntax along the way, but for this code example is in exercises and use some concept I haven't know yet. My goal is learn FP but now I feel Scala in also interesting to learn. :)

Comment: @Mengo If you decide that you also want to learn **Scala**, I would recommend you to frist read the [**tour of scala**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html) and then read [**essential scala**](https://underscore.io/books/essential-scala/) _(or any other scala introduction book)_ before continuing with the red book.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks for the links! I'll do my best to catch up with both!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a slightly more verbose version of `simulateMachine` that should be a bit easier to understand.

```
def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = for {
    _ <- State.sequence(  // this _ means "discard this 'unpacked' value"
      inputs.map(
        (State.modify[Machine] _).compose(update) // this _ is an eta-expansion
      )
    )
    s <- State.get
  } yield (s.coins, s.candies)
```

**"Unpacked" value** - `for { value <- container } ...` basically "unpacks" `value` from `container`. Semantics of unpacking is different between different containers - the most straightforward is `List` or `Seq` semantics, where `value` each item of the becomes `value` and `for` semantics in this case becomes just iteration. Other notable "containers" are:

- `Option` - `for` semantics: value present or not + modifications of the value if present
- `Try` - `for` semantics: successful computation or not + modifications of the successful
- `Future` - `for` semantics: defining a chain of computations to perform when value becomes present

Practically, each monad (explaining what monad is is haaard :) Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44965/what-is-a-monad) as a starting point) defines the way to "unpack" and "iterate". Your `State` is practically a monad (even though it doesn't declare this explicitly) (and btw, there's a canonical `State` monad you can find in 3rd party libs such as [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html) or [scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/State.html))

**Eta-expansion** is explained in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala), but in short it converts a function/method into a function object. Roughly equivalent to `x => State.modify[Machine](x)`

Or a completely desugared version:

```
def simulateMachine(inputs: List[Input]): State[Machine, (Int, Int)] = {
    val simulationStep: Input => State[Machine, Unit] = (State.modify[Machine] _).compose(update) // this _ is an eta-expansion

    State.sequence(inputs.map(input => simulationStep(input)))
      .flatMap(_ => State.get)  // `_ => xyz` creates a function that does not care about it's input
      .map(machine => (machine.candies, machine.coins))
  }
```

Note that the use of `_` in `_ => State.get` is yet another way `_` is used - now **it creates a function that doesn't care about it's argument**.

Now, answering questions as they are asked:

1. See above :)
2. If you look at desugared version, you'd see that the `State.get` is passed as a "callback" to `flatMap`. There are a few hoops to jump through to trace it (I'll leave it as an exercise for you :)), but essentially what it does is to replace the "result" part of the state (`A`) with the state itself (`S`)). Trick here is that it does not get the `Machine` at all - it just "chains" a call to "fetch" the `Machine` from the `S` part of state to `A` part of state.
3. I think desugared version should be pretty self-explanatory. Regarding the for-comprehension version - `for` fixes the "context" using the first call in the chain, so everything else (including `yield`) is executed in that "context" - specifically, it's fixed to `State[_, _]`. `yield` is essentially equivalent to calling `map` at the end of the chain, and in `State[_, _]` semantics, map replaces the `A` part, but preserves the `S` part.
4. `Candy.simulateMachine(List(Coin, Turn, Coin, Turn)).run(Machine(false, 2, 0))`

P.S. your current code still misses `State.set` method. I'm assuming it's just `def set[S](s: => S): State[S, S] = State(_ => (s, s))` - at least adding this makes your snippet compile in my environment.

Comment: Much appreciated! I added `State.set`. I wish I can give 100 up vote for this!