# Scala map with postfixOps

Tags: scala, function

Can someone explain why nums.map(+2) does not work but nums.map(2+) works?

```
scala> val nums=List(1,2,3,4)
nums: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

scala>  nums.map(2+)
res3: List[Int] = List(3, 4, 5, 6)

scala> nums.map(+2)
<console>:27: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(2)
 required: Int => ?
       nums.map(+2)
                ^
```

Answer (score 6):

Look at the signature for `map()`:

```
final def map[B](f: (A) => B): List[B]
```

The argument, `f`, is a function from `A` to `B`. `2+` fulfills that function requirement because it is a syntactic shorthand for `2.+(_)`. In other words, the `+()` method invoked on an instance of the `Int` class, turned into a proper function via [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445018/what-is-the-eta-expansion-in-scala?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C157.5604).

If you want the `+` before the `2` then you can `.map(_+2)`.

Comment: And `+2` is simply the *positive integer two*.