# Function composition results in missing argument list for method first

Tags: scala, functional-programming, composition

Suppose we have the following functions:

```
def first(a: A): B = ???
def second(b: B): C = ???
```

I would like to compose them using `andThen`, but the following code:

```
(first andThen second)(a)
```

results in:

```
<console>:14: error: missing argument list for method first
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `first _` or `first(_)` instead of `first`.                                                                                                                                                                    
(first andThen second) (1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`andThen()` is a method on a `Function`. As you've defined it, `first()` is a method (`def`), not a function. Those are [different entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2529184/4993128).

You could define it as a function...

```
val first : A => B = (a:A) => ???
```

... or you can use [eta expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39445018/4993128) to promote it to function status.

```
(first _ andThen second)
```

Word has it that Scala 3 will offer a more transparent eta expansion mechanism so that the distinction between method and function won't be quite as cumbersome.

Comment: Indeed `(first andThen second)` works in dotty https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NbFxsVSESnaccp2ysxb9JA